# Какие слова пригодны в данном случае?

Tags: лексика

Как сказать об отделении пассажирским модулем топливного бака при взлете ракет?

Бак отстреливают, отпускают, сбрасывают, он отходит?

Можно ли этот бак назвать балластом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Балластом этот бак называть нельзя. Ибо балласт по определению есть мёртвый груз, т.е. груз, заведомо не несущий полезной нагрузки.

В космонавтике баки отстреливают. (А о ступенях принято говорить, что они отделяются.)